# Excel columns to match and put the values in newly created columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have 4 columns "Restaurant Name" ,"Delivery" ,"SecondName" and "Longitude-Latitude". I want to check "Restaurant Name" in the whole column of "SecondName" and if the rows match then it should pick up the Values from "Delivery" and "Longitude-Latitude" columns and put it separately into the new columns of "Result1 " , "Result2".

[image]

Note : number of rows of Restaurant column and "SecondName" columns are not same but all the names of "Restaurant" column exist in the "SecondName" column.

Please help me how to do it. It will be great help for me.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Harun24HR its working fine now.

Comment: Then please consider accepting my answer means tick mark the answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Result: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))`,

For Result2: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))`

Comment: Thanks  @Andrew Doroshenko its working fine now.

Comment: @ArslanAhmadZaheer glad that it works! It would be nice if you mark the answer as 'useful' or 'accepted'. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `INDEXT()/MATCH()` combination to return delivery and lat-long. Try-

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))
```

If you have multiple delivery for same restaurant and want to pick last delivery then follow the below procedure.

As you are using `Excel2010` you have to use some array formula. Array formulas need to enter by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`. Try below formula-

```
 =INDEX($B$2:$B$25,LARGE(IF($C$2:$C$25=$A2,ROW($C$2:$C$25)-1,""),1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

For `G2` cell

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$25,LARGE(IF($C$2:$C$25=$A2,ROW($C$2:$C$25)-1,""),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you. I really appreciate it. Take care